# Django MySQL ORM commented out 'use_index'. w

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, orm

**my command :**

```
qs = model.objects.force_index('idx_sensorid_id_accelerator').filter(sensor_id=dev['id']).order_by('-id').values(*cols)
```

**and my index (mysql) :**

#### STATISTICS

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sensor_accelerator | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 131673992 | \N | \N |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| sensor_accelerator | 1 | sensor_accelerator_sensor_id_b0bf304a | 1 | sensor_id | A | 19720 | \N | \N |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| sensor_accelerator | 1 | sensor_accelerator_added_c16fd96c | 1 | added | A | 131673992 | \N | \N |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| sensor_accelerator | 1 | idx_sensorid_id_accelerator | 1 | sensor_id | A | 19714 | \N | \N |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| sensor_accelerator | 1 | idx_sensorid_id_accelerator | 2 | id | D | 131673992 | \N | \N |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| sensor_accelerator | 1 | idx_sensorid_added_accelerator | 1 | sensor_id | A | 15368 | \N | \N |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| sensor_accelerator | 1 | idx_sensorid_added_accelerator | 2 | added | D | 131673992 | \N | \N |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |

but the query result is :

```
SELECT `sensor_accelerator`.`sensor_id`, `sensor_accelerator`.`id`, `sensor_accelerator`.`x`, `sensor_accelerator`.`y`, `sensor_accelerator`.`z`, `sensor_accelerator`.`temp`, `sensor_accelerator`.`time`, `sensor_accelerator`.`added`

FROM `sensor_accelerator`

WHERE ((/*QueryRewrite':index=`sensor_accelerator` USE `sensor_accelerator_sensor_id_b0bf304a`*/1)

AND `sensor_accelerator`.`sensor_id` = 'A0011')

ORDER BY `sensor_accelerator`.`id` DESC

LIMIT 1
```

what i expected is :

```
SELECT `sensor_accelerator`.`sensor_id`, `sensor_accelerator`.`id`, `sensor_accelerator`.`x`, `sensor_accelerator`.`y`, `sensor_accelerator`.`z`, `sensor_accelerator`.`temp`, `sensor_accelerator`.`time`, `sensor_accelerator`.`added`

FROM `sensor_accelerator`

USE INDEX (idx_sensorid_id_accelerator)

WHERE `sensor_accelerator`.`sensor_id` = 'A0011'

ORDER BY `sensor_accelerator`.`id` DESC

LIMIT 1
```

Why django orm commented out use_index phrase?